# Incorportar Mercado Envio en el modulo de Mercado Pago de Wordpres

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, woocommerce

Buenas, estoy comenzando con woocommerce y mercado pago. Instale el modulo oficial de mercado pago, pero no encuentro la manera de utilizar mercado envio. Alguién a podido integrar mercado envio en wordpress con woocommercer???